# Chrome failing to load image with a src url that is a redirected url

Tags: php, image, google-chrome, url

I have a Merchant, which for example purposes is 1800Lighting.com, and I store the logo url for said merchant in my database.

The url that is handed to me is this http://www.ftjcfx.com/image-6201334-10737084

That url clicked in a browser redirects to this http://www.yceml.net/0444/10737084-2.jpg

The problem that I am having is when I put an image into the html page with the src attribute being the url that I am given ( the first image link ), Google Chrome fails to load the image. The developer console says "Failed to load resource." Firefox loads the image just fine. I am at my wits end trying to figure this one out, and have tried everything I can think of.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is what I am printing to the page.

```
<img src="http://www.ftjcfx.com/image-6201334-10737084" alt="icon"
class="shoppingCatIcon"/>
```

Comment: can not reproduce on Chrome 26.0.1410.63 linux

Comment: Try turning off Adblock if you have it activated - I can't even get to those images from work because they're blocked with reason: adware.

Comment: Also, cannot reproduce on Chrome Version 27.0.1453.94 Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was adblock!

The images are blocked for me at work due to reason:adware.

When I try from home with adblock turned up, it fails.

Always try without the plugins!

Comment: Thanks Zind! Easy solution :)